# cursor.requery() -error

Tags: android, cursor, simplecursoradapter

How i can update a Cursor data?
 cursorComp.requery() -causes an error

Code:

```
  void someTask() {
 try
 {
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
 for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++) 
  {
     JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
     extId = json_data.getString("id");
     nameComp = json_data.getString("name");
    db.addRec(nameComp,extId,compDescription,minPrice);
    //update cursor
    cursorComp.requery(); //This line generates an error
  }
 }
 }
```

Comment: `requery()` is deprecated better to re-initialized your cursor.

Comment: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.